# How to pass a parameter from main report to sub report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to pass my parameter value from main report to the sub report.

I have tried many ways. Also I have tried options from this link as well 
[passing-parameters-from-main-report-to-subreport-to-subreport-in-jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843167/passing-parameters-from-main-report-to-subreport-to-subreport-in-jasper)

**Main report**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.0  -->
<!-- 2016-01-03T00:04:36 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="parademo" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="4949f116-97b5-453c-8581-61ccb1b3159e">
    <parameter name="TITLEPARA" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["hi title"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="180" y="36" width="220" height="30" uuid="4ac55979-2248-45d2-a001-3c82b5fec56b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{TITLEPARA}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="286" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport runToBottom="false">
                <reportElement x="0" y="86" width="560" height="74" uuid="eca8556b-2d65-462f-a3d3-ac95ea6e3ebf"/>
                <subreportParameter name="TITLEPARA">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{TITLEPARA}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["file:/home/rectrix/workspace/jasper/subparam.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Sub-Report**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.0  -->
<!-- 2016-01-03T00:04:17 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="subparam" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="b4c019e3-0dc2-425c-b449-908c4fd21bde">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="MainReportDataSet"/>
    <parameter name="TITLEPARA" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="45" width="100" height="30" uuid="6b9d5038-4163-47ed-a0cd-812f07b27ff0"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{TITLEPARA}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

I am able to print "HI TITLE" Using the parameter in my main report's `title` band.

I want to pass this value to the sub-report using the parameter and print it on the `title` band of the sub-report.

I want to pass this value using a parameter only, because I want to know how the parameters works so I could use it for my project to pass the values to sub-report through parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the parameter **correctly**, this is not your issue.

Using your example files you have these issues.

1. If the datasource is empty you need attribute `whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail"` on `jasperReport` tag to display something (both in main and subreport).
2. The subreport can not be in the `detail` band (since your datasource is empty), move it into another band example `title` band.
3. You can not reference a **jrxml** in `subreportExpression`, you need to reference a `.jasper` file (the `jrxml` when it has been complied). Note: the path need's to be the absolute path to the file (you normally use a parameter for this so that you can pass it in runtime)

see this for more information on path to subreport [Subreport not rendering in main report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34508171/subreport-not-rendering-in-main-report/34530546#34530546)

For testing I suggest you to put another static text element in the subreport, so that you understand if the subreport is displayed or not.

Comment: Sir the First point of your I didn't get it properly... Can u elaborate and explain why. And how exactly to it in jaspersoft studio

Comment: Oh, Thank you sir I found a way set that whenNoDataType, But can u please explain what exactly it does.

Comment: It is an "Empty Data Source Behavior", when you have no data (empty datasource), what should the report do?... default behavior is NoPages (so no band will be displayed), since you did not pass any data to subreport it was simply not displaying anything.... for more information about whenNoDataType see http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRReport.html

Comment: what if the main report has page header and page footer then where should the subreport be placed?

subreport have parameters filled by passing data from Java.

Comment: @DhruvilThaker you can't put it in title band (since no footer or header is displayed), or use the summary band (check the attribute isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true") or use the detail band passing 1 empty record datasource